# Physical meaning of $\langle nlm|\hat{z}|n'l'm'\rangle$

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, wavefunction, symmetry, hydrogen

I'm working on a quantum mechanics problem with some friends and we're trying to make an argument using symmetry rather than maths. What would the physical interpretation of $\langle nlm|\hat{z}|n'l'm'\rangle$ be for two states of the Hydrogen atom?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The simplest interpretation would be as a transition amplitude.  If an electric dipole oriented along the $z$ axis interacted with your atom, the probability of
transition from $\vert n'l'm'\rangle$ to $\vert nlm\rangle$ would be proportional to
\begin{align}
\vert \langle nlm\vert \hat z \vert n'l'm'\rangle\vert^2\, .
\end{align}

Note that the operator $\hat z$ can only connect $n'$ with $n=n'\pm 1$, $l$ with $l'=l\pm 1$ and $m'=m$.  If the orientation was different there could be a change in the magnetic quantum numbers.  The process $n'\to n'+1$ is clearly absorption whereas $n'\to n'-1$ is emission.